# How to update the node status?

Tags: 8, nodes, entities

I'm using data from JSON to create new nodes or update fields on existing if node exist on my Drupal 8 website. So, when I use method to update nodes, I need to save in array node id of updated nodes and keys of fields with changed values in this node.

After update is finished I need to print table with all nodes of this content type where fields of updated nodes need to have different style (color, background, etc).

So if my old node have 
`body = "body1"` and `description  = "description 1"` and new node have `body = "body2"`and `description  = "description 1"` after update is finished i need to get output like this:

[image]

Here is an example:

```
$node = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load($nid);
$node->set("body", 'New body text');
$node->set("description", 'New value');
$node->save();
```

Any suggestion?

**Note**: when I use `$node->save();` if all updated values is same nothing is changed (date of node in content from admin panel is same as before update), but if values is different I need to store node id, keys and values only of changed fields in array.

Comment: Not really clear when and how you want to have that output, but as suggested by one answer, if you use the diff module and save a new revision, then you get a diff between the old and new values for any change that you ever made (assuming you stored it as a new revision)

Answer (score 10):

To set the status you can use the [setPublished()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21src%21Entity%21Node.php/function/Node%3A%3AsetPublished/8.2.x) method:

> **public function Node::setPublished**
>
> Sets the published status of a node..
>
> **Parameters**
>
> ***bool $published***: **TRUE** to set this node to published, **FALSE** to set it
>   to unpublished.

In your case:

```
$node = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load($nid);
$node->set("body", 'New body text');
$node->set("field_name", 'New value');
$node->setPublished(TRUE);
```

Comment: Status is ok, I have this in my code.
I need something different, for example when I get data from JSON, some fields have same values, i just need to know which field have different value from previous.

Comment: @StevanRS I think that you need to explain better your question, and then let me know.

Comment: The node status in Drupal refers to its published state. So, without clarification, this is the answer. Another way to look for a node that has been updated without looking at published state is to look at its `changed` property, the time it was last modified.

Comment: @Adrian Cid Almaguer when i use $node->save(); if all updated values is same nothing is changed (date of node in content from admin panel is same as before update), but if values is different i need to store node id, keys and values only of changed fields in array.

Comment: @StevanRS can you edit your question and add an example please? I can't get the point

Comment: Note that passing a `true`/`false` to `$node->setPublished()` is [deprecated as of 8.3.x](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityPublishedTrait.php/function/EntityPublishedTrait%3A%3AsetPublished/8.8.x). Instead use `$node->setPublished()` to publish and `$node->setUnpublished()` to unpublish.

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget the node->save() or your node changes will be ignored.

```
$node = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load($nid);
$node->set("body", 'New body text');
$node->set("field_name", 'New value');
$node->setPublished(TRUE);
$node->save();
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you save a new revision of the updated node? Maybe you can use the diff module to see the changes between the current & previous node?
This is not an in depth solution, but maybe could be useful pointer for you.

Answer (score -2):

you can un publish by setting status to 0

```
          $node = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load($nids);
          //set Unpublishing node
          $node->status = 0;
          //save to update node
          $node->save();
```

Comment: This is not good advice. You really should be using setPublished() instead of accessing the status property directly. The existing answers cover this adequately.