# Status on node is not changed during query update

Tags: nodes

I'm updating a node's status to unpublished and the status in `node_field_data` is changed from 1 to 0 but in the content view, status is published and when editing the node, the publish checkbox is still checked.

What am I missing?

```
Drupal::database()->update('node_field_data')
->condition('nid', $nids, 'IN')
->fields(['status' => NodeInterface::NOT_PUBLISHED])
->execute();
```

Comment: It could be the data is still cached. Executing a query on the database isn't going to clear the cache.

Comment: Yeah try with something like this instead https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/234504/how-to-update-the-node-status

Comment: A better way to do this in Drupal 8 is like this,     ```$nodes = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->loadMultiple($nids);
    foreach ($nodes as $node) {
      $node->setPublished(FALSE);
      $node->save();
    }```